# How run a python console script from a hiding console python script?

Tags: python, tkinter, console

I'm not very experienced in python and I start building an app with Tkinter.
Like it's a window project I open it with pythonw.exe but it call a console script and I can't display the console of the second script if the first is hidden ...
There is the piece of code which call the second script :

```
from selenium_script import main    

self.btn_downloadAnime = tk.Button(self.frm_addAnime, text='Lunch download script with voiranime.com links',
                                       bg=self.colorBTN, font=22, activebackground=self.colorBG, height=2, width=50,
                                       command=main)
```

Comment: I don't know if that's possible but have you tried creating a new process and running the other python script there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

`main.py`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import sys

COMMAND = "start python selenium_script.py"

def start_new_proc():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(COMMAND, close_fds=False, shell=True)

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, command=start_new_proc, text="Start new process")
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`selenium_script.py`:

```py
user_input = input(">>> ")
print("You typed this: " + str(user_input))
input("Press enter to exit.")
```

I start a new process using `subprocess.Popen`. The new process starts with its own shell (because of the `"start"` in the `COMMAND` variable)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was missing the notion of process ...
The previous solution works and I found one too :

```
def open_selenium(self):
        subprocess.Popen(args=['python', 'selenium2.py'], stdout=sys.stdout)
```